# Find the Cubic equation given 1 Point and Slope

Tags: cubics

The question asks to find a cubic equation given point A (0/18) slope here is 0. Point B only given the x=20 and slope is -0.6.

Please help, been trying to solve it for so long now. :(

1.) y=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d

2.) y'=3ax^2+2bx+c

-0,6=1200a+40b+1c

18=0a+0b+0c+1d

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please show us what you have tried so far 
and where you are stuck and in what context you have encountered the problem
, i.e edit your post with this information. 
This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: Just to be clear, you are told that  $y(0) = 18$, $y'(0) = 0$, and $y'(20) = -0.6$. Is that correct? If so, that's not enough information to **uniquely** define a cubic, but you could find **some** cubic.

Comment: 20 is the distance from Point A and on that point the slope is -0,6. (German native speaker, so excuse my bad english please)

Comment: the equation should be y(x)=0,0005x^3-0,03x^2+18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote is not very clear. But, if I understand it correctly, you are only given three pieces of information -- one function value and two slopes. From this, you won't be able to calculate unique values for the four unknowns $a,b,c,d$.

But, as the comment from @Justin points out, you could find *some* values of $a,b,c,d$ that will work:
\begin{align}
y(0) &= 18 \; \Rightarrow \; d = 18  \\
y'(0) &= 0 \; \Rightarrow \; c = 0  \\
y'(20) &= -0.6 \; \Rightarrow \; 1200a+40b+c = -0.6
\end{align}
From the third equation, we get $1200a+40b = -0.6$. We can just set $a=1$, arbitrarily, and then we get $b = -1200.6/40 = -30.015$.

So, a suitable cubic (but not the only one) is:
$$
y = x^3 -30.015x^2 + 18
$$

Comment: thank you, but the answer should be y(x)=0,0005x^3-0,03x^2+18 ?!

Comment: There is no **the** answer. There are an infinite number of cubics that will work. Mine is just as good as yours  :-). Check it, and you'll see that it works.

Comment: how is a=1? why is b -1200,6/40 ??

Comment: You can choose any value you like for $a$. The only requirement is that $1200a+40b = -0.6$. I just picked $a=1$ to make things easy. In your solution, they picked $a = 0.0005$. Both are correct.

Comment: why is b -0,03 in my equation shouldn't it be the same then ?

Comment: No. It's always true that $b = (-0.6 - 1200a)/40$. Changing $a$ will require that you change $b$, also.

Answer (score 0):

You have too little information, but the general method is:

Write the general equation for a cubic, differentiate it, and plug in the information you have in those two expressions. That will give you a set of equations to solve.

But the information you mention will only give three equations with four unknonwns.

And you haven't used that the slope at $0$ is $0$.

Comment: I don't think so. He'll only get three equations, and he has 4 unknowns.

Comment: @bubba: Right, I edited my answer to mention that.

Comment: The problem only asks for _a_ cubic. So there should be an infinite family of cubics any one of which will work.